# Como montar um Select para unir colunas

Tags: c#, sql, select

Eu estou com uma dúvida que nem sei se é possível, ela é a seguinte:

Gostaria de realizar um select que uni-se duas colunas.

De outra forma seria:

Tabela Pessoa com os campos cod_pessoa - nome - rg - razao_social - cnpj

Tabela Cliente com campo cod_cliente - cod_pessoa

O conceito do select seria:  Buscar todos os clientes apresentando cod_cliente - nome/razao_social - rg/cnpj

Exemplo de dados registrado:
Tabela Pessoa:

```
cod_pessoa  | Nome    | Rg            | Razao_Social       | Cnpj
1           | Luis    | 10.100.100-1  |                    |
2           | Carlos  | 20.200.200-2  |                    |
3           |         |               |Lanchonete do Paulo | 30.300.300/3000-30
```

Tabela Cliente

```
cod_cliente  | cod_pessoa
1            | 1
2            | 2
3            | 3
```

Eu gostaria que o resultado fosse o seguinte:

```
cod_cliente  | Nome/Razao_social     |  Cpf/Cnpj
1            | Luis                  | 10.100.100-1
2            | Carlos                | 20.200.200-2
3            | Lanchonete do Paulo   | 30.300.300/3000-30
```

Eu gostaria de obter esse resulta pois estou realizando um projeto no C# e em um dos form's eu realizo um pesquisa dos clientes o resultado alimenta um dataGrid. E o resultado visual do que eu estou querendo ficaria mais agradável do um resultado com lacunas em branco.

Eu já tentei de diversas formas, a que chegou mais próximo foi essa:

```
select cli.cod_cliente, pes.nome, pes.cpf from tab_Cliente cli
inner join tab_Pessoa pes on cli.cod_pessoa = pes.cod_pessoa
where pes.nome like '%%' --(condição)
union
select cli.cod_cliente, pes.razao_social, pes.cnpj from tab_Cliente cli
inner join tab_Pessoa pes on cli.cod_pessoa = pes.cod_pessoa
where pes.razao_social like '%%' --(condição)
```

Obs: a condição sera igual em ambos os select's

Ele une as colunas mas ele apresenta algumas falhas como: traz lacunas em branco quando recebe vazio na condição ou não traz nada quando na condição recebe 'igual' ao dado do banco.

Desde já fico grato com qualquer sugestão.

--Atualização-- Resposta - baseada na resposta do dil_oliveira -Muito Obrigado

**Banco Utilizado Sql Server

```
select 
  cli.cod_cliente, 
  (case when LEN(lTRIM(pes.nome)) > 0 then 
     Nome   
  else
     Razao_Social
  end) as 'Nome/Razao_social',
  (case when LEN(lTRIM(pes.rg)) > 0 then 
     Rg    
  else
     Cnpj
  end) as 'Cpf/Cnpj'
from tab_Pessoa pes
inner join tab_Cliente cli 
on pes.cod_pessoa = cli.cod_pessoa
where pes.nome like '%%' or pes.razao_social like '%%' order by 'Nome/Razao_social'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não especificou o banco e este código funciona no MySQL, para outros SGDBs procure correspondentes para as funções LENGTH e TRIM;

```
select 
  cod_cliente, 
  (case when LENGTH(TRIM(Nome)) > 0 then 
     Nome   
  else
     Razao_Social
  end) as 'Nome/Razao_social',
  (case when LENGTH(TRIM(Rg)) > 0 then 
     Rg    
  else
     Cnpj
  end) as 'Cpf/Cnpj'
from Pessoa
inner join Cliente 
on Pessoa.cod_pessoa = Cliente.cod_pessoa
```

Existe uma maneira mais prática de resolver seu problema, por exemplo, criando uma coluna na tabela Pessoa para definir se o tipo de registro é pessoa ou empresa.

Comment: É isso mesmo, muito obrigado. Eu utilizo o Sql Server. Vou editar o meu post só ajustando o seu código para o Sql Server.